# Conditional returns or single variable return

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

I was wondering what if there's any preferable way of returning values conditionally.
And if not, if it makes any different for minified Javascript.

I was checking [Google Javascript Style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) and they don't name anything about the issue. Same with [Airbnb guidelines](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables)

Using multiple conditional returns:

```
function demo(x, y) {
   if (x < y) {
       return getX();
   } else if (x === y) {
       return 'equal';
   }
   return getY();
}
```

Or having a single return with and making use of a variable:

```
function demo(x, y) {
    var position;

    if (x < y) {
        position = getX();
    } else if (x === y) {
       position = 'equal';
    } else {
        position = getY();
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Or ternary operator? `var position = x < y ? getX() : getY(); return position;`

Comment: @Tushar lets say we have 3 conditions :)

Comment: Google doesn't specify because Closure-compiler will optimize either method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a definition of the [return statement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp).

> The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value from that function.

Clearly, a conditional return would have to include a condition before that `return`.
About **preference**, as the word implies, it is really is a matter of habits.
If you're used to one syntax from, say, another language, or you just like it better - use it, as it will probably reduce syntax errors.

About minifying the code, I believe the switch/case syntax best works for simple conditions, and the ternary operation fits well for two-side conditions.

(Caution! philosophical paragraph ahead)

But again, in the end, the important thing, I believe, is that you will understand the code you write. And, with experience, you will find what suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

You should concern yourself with readability. Write the code in the way that is most understandable.  If you are returning from with a deeply nest condition that is likely to be confusing to future read, but if you have a series of early exits at the start of your function that is likely to make the code more readable (when compared to deep nesting).  Break up big functions and leave mangling to the compilers. The Closure Compiler will produce the same results for either of your examples.

Examples:

[http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Afunction%2520demo1(x%252C%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520position%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(x%2520%253C%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520position%2520%253D%2520getX()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520if%2520(x%2520%253D%253D%253D%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520position%2520%253D%2520'equal'%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520position%2520%253D%2520getY()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520position%253B%250A%257D%250A%250Afunction%2520demo2(x%252C%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520if%2520(x%2520%253C%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520getX()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520if%2520(x%2520%253D%253D%253D%2520y)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520'equal'%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520return%2520getY()%253B%250A%257D](http://example)

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary/conditional operator.

In Javascript conditional operator can evaluate to an expression, not just a statement.

```
var result = x < y ? getX() : getY();
```

This starts evaluation from left and if your condition meets criteria then result will be the first portion otherwise result would be second portion.

For more conditions you have to use it like

```
 var result = IsYoungerThan18 ? serveMilk() : IsYoungerThan21 ? serveBear() : serveWine();
```

So in your case it should be

```
var result = (x < y) ? getX() : (x == y) ? "equal" : getY();
```

Comment: Ok, lets image 3 conditions then. I updated my question.

Comment: OP here do not want any other way to do the same. OP want to know which way is better/followed

Comment: @Tushar I think OP has mentioned a minified way of doing same thing rather than writing 7/8 lines of if else.

Comment: @Neel no, when I talked about minified Javascript I was referring to Closure Compiler, UglifyJS etc.